# Redirection operator in echo without lvalue?

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

I have found following code in **N**ginx `configure` script:

```
    echo > $NGX_AUTO_HEADERS_H
    echo > $NGX_AUTOCONF_ERR
```

I was thinking that this is the same as do `VAR=`, that will simply set variable for the empty value, but when I do it I got the error:

```
echo > $VAR
-bash: $VAR: ambiguous redirect
```

Also it will not set the variable to empty value when initialized:

```
VAR=10
echo > $VAR
echo "$VAR"
10
```

So why this statements are in place, what is their purpose?

Comment: It should write a newline to the file specified by the variable.

Comment: Hard to say. `echo > $foo` will write a single newline to a file whose name comes from the first word resulting from the expansion of `$foo`. If that file exists, it (effectively) truncates the file (though `printf > ...` would be better, as it wouldn't even write a newline).

Comment: `echo > $VAR` doesn't initialize a variable, it initializes a *file* specified by the variable. If the variable isn't defined, it can't figure out what file it should initialize, so you get the "ambiguous redirect" error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! The syntax above (of course) will create or empty a file pointed by variable.